# Parse MM/DD from MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM string Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, parsing

I'm trying to extract MM/DD as a string from a date formatted MM/DD/YY HH:MM.

I've tried using left() but the problem is that some days have 1 character and some have 2. So, in some cases, / shows up.

```
Date    Date Formatted
3/12/19 12:23   3/12
3/12/19 12:47   3/12
3/13/19 5:43    3/13
3/18/19 14:43   3/18
3/19/19 7:12    3/19
3/19/19 7:50    3/19
3/19/19 7:50    3/19
3/19/19 12:17   3/19
3/19/19 20:38   3/19
3/20/19 7:37    3/20
3/21/19 14:49   3/21
3/26/19 13:05   3/26
4/2/19 8:11 4/2/
4/2/19 8:11 4/2/
4/2/19 8:11 4/2/
4/2/19 8:12 4/2/
4/2/19 8:13 4/2/
4/2/19 8:14 4/2/
```

I've also tried changing the date format to MM/DD but when I create a chart or pivot table, Excel still recognizes the embedded HH:MM and add unwanted data that to the chart/table.

I want MM/DD as a string. I don't want to use text --> columns, because I want a formula that auto updates as I add more data into the data set.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just use built in functions to extract month and day and concat them together along with your / `=MONTH(A1) &"/"&DAY(A1)`  This does assume you have a true date field to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a date formatted cell is in A1...

`=MONTH(A1) &"/"&DAY(A1)`

or 
`=IF(A1<>"",MONTH(A1) &"/"&DAY(A1),"")` if you want to blank dates and fill a larger range of the column.

Comment: Ah. I knew it didn't need to be complex :) thank you!

Comment: 1/2 the battle is just knowing what features/functions exist ;P

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your data in cell A1 and it is in m/dd/yy hh:mm format. To split the date alone from there i am using datevalue function along with left text function. So the datevalue function would help to convert the text date to its appropriate date value as a number according to excel stored value. The left function would help to split the appropriate text characters related to date before the blank space from the unrecognized data.

=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))

Hope this is in order and it will work to help on your process.